# Filtering by secondary field in DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I'm new to DAX.

My model contains a single table called `Notices`. Notices has 235,969 rows.

Notices has fields `CustomerID`, `NoticeNo` and `NoticeStatus`.

When I set the filter context to `'CANCL' Notices[NoticeStatus]`, I can see that there are 3 notices that have a `CANCL` status.

As such, the measure below evaluates to 3 since each of the remaining notices belong to 3 separate customers. However, I would like to base the aggregate on the unfiltered table, but filter out the rows (after aggregating) based on the CustomerIDs that remain in the filter context and `[ObCount] = 1`. In this case, the measure needs to evaluate to 0 or `BLANK()`, as none of the CustomerIDs in the filter context remain after filtering for `[ObCount] = 1`.

```
Customers with Single Notice Only = 
COUNTROWS (
    FILTER (
        SUMMARIZECOLUMNS (
            Notices[CustomerID],
            Notices,     
            "ObCount", [All Notices Outstanding]
        ),
        [ObCount] = 1
    )
)
```

`[All Notices Outstanding] = COUNTROWS(Notices)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this by applying the filtered table as a table filter argument to `Notices` using CALCULATE:

```
Customers with Single Notice Only =
CALCULATE (
    COUNTROWS ( Notices ),
    FILTER (
        SUMMARIZECOLUMNS (
            Notices[CustomerID],
            ALL ( Notices ),
            "ObCount", [All Notices Outstanding]
        ),
        [ObCount] = 1
    )
)
```

Note the use of ALL to remove the filter status filter when summarizing.

Comment: That works. I'm still struggling to get my head around the calculate function.